# Java HashMap gives wrong values for the given key

Tags: java, hashmap, hash-collision

I am using a Map of type `Map<Integer, HashMap<String, List<Employee>>>`. After populating the map, if I immediately retrieve some values using the `String` key, the returned `List<Employee>` is correct. But after some iteration the values are changing.

After populating the map the first time, I have not used `map.put` anywhere, only used `map.get()`.

```java
private Map<Integer, HashMap<String, List<Employee>>> createDataMap(List<Employee> employeeList) {

    for(Employee e:employeeList){       
        Map<Integer, HashMap<String, List<Employee>>> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        int level = Integer.parseInt(e.getLevel());
        HashMap<String, List<Employee>> detailsMap = dataMap.get(level);
        if (Objects.isNull(detailsMap)) {
            detailsMap = new HashMap<>();
            dataMap.put(level, detailsMap);
        }
        String deptName = key.getDepartment();
        List<Employee> keyList = detailsMap.get(deptName);
        if (Objects.isNull(keyList)) {
            keyList = new ArrayList<>();
            detailsMap.put(dataMapKey, keyList);
        }
        keyList.add(key);
    }
    return dataMap;
}
```

Comment: Provide your code?

Comment: To simplify your code, you get use the ```getOrDefault``` of the class ```Map``` instead of testing if the value of your map is null after getting it

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. `dataMap` is constructed per-employee *in the loop* then returned *outside* the loop. That won't even compile. In general, please look into `detailsMap = map.computeIfAbsent(level, HashMap::New)` which handles the conditional-creation logic

Answer (score 0):

- **dataMap** needs to be instantiated only once, outside of the loop.
- When you use **key** it should be **e**, you should make sure whatever code you post compiles (as a minimum!)
- `detailsMap.put(dataMapKey, keyList);` is not correct, should be `detailsMap.put(e.getDepartment(), keyList);`

I think that is what your code should look like. It now compiles and correctly creates your Map. I took the liberty to rename some variables to make it more readable.

```
private static Map<Integer, HashMap<String, List<Employee>>> createDataMap2(List<Employee> employeeList) {
    Map<Integer, HashMap<String, List<Employee>>> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(Employee e:employeeList){

        // Get the departments for the employee's level
        int level = Integer.parseInt(e.getLevel());
        HashMap<String, List<Employee>> departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel = dataMap.get(level);
        if (Objects.isNull(departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel)) {
            departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel = new HashMap<>();
            dataMap.put(level, departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel);
        }

        // Get the employee list for the employee's department
        String deptName = e.getDepartment();
        List<Employee> employeesListForEmployeeLevelAndDepartment = departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel.get(deptName);
        if (Objects.isNull(employeesListForEmployeeLevelAndDepartment)) {
            employeesListForEmployeeLevelAndDepartment = new ArrayList<>();
            departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel.put(deptName, employeesListForEmployeeLevelAndDepartment);
        }

        // add the employee to its department list
        employeesListForEmployeeLevelAndDepartment.add(e);
    }

    return dataMap;
}
```

Also as mentioned in the comments, this can be further simplified using `Map.getOrDefault`.

```
private static Map<Integer, HashMap<String, List<Employee>>> createDataMap2(List<Employee> employeeList) {
    Map<Integer, HashMap<String, List<Employee>>> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(Employee employee: employeeList){
        int level = Integer.parseInt(employee.getLevel());
        String deptName = employee.getDepartment();

        // get the list of department employees for level
        HashMap<String, List<Employee>> departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel = 
                dataMap.getOrDefault(level, new HashMap<>());
        // get the list of employees for level and department
        List<Employee> employeesListForEmployeeLevelAndDepartment = 
                departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel.getOrDefault(deptName, new ArrayList<>());

        // add employee to its department for its level
        employeesListForEmployeeLevelAndDepartment.add(employee);
        // set new employee list to the employee's department
        departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel.put(deptName, employeesListForEmployeeLevelAndDepartment);
        // set the updated department to the employee's level
        dataMap.put(level, departmentsEmployeesMapForEmployeeLevel);
    }

    return dataMap;
}
```